# Can I get all the beans in a method annotated with @PostConstruct?

Tags: java, spring

As far as I know, A method annotated with @PostConstruct will be executed after its bean has been initialized.

So can I get all the beans in this method?
Like this...

```
@CustomAnnotation
public class Foo {
}

@Service
public class TestBean {
   @Autowired
   private Application context;

   @PostContruct
   public void init() {
      // get all beans annotated with @CustomAnnotation
      context.getBeansWithAnnotation(CustomAnnotation.class);
      // to do something...
   }
}
```

If the TestBean is initialized before the Foo, does the Foo can be detected in init()?

Comment: Did you mean `@Autowired` instead of `@Autoware`?

Comment: @Loading... Thank you for reminding me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring initialization has at least two distinct steps when it comes to singleton beans.

Before the actual singleton bean instances are created, and your `@PostConstruct` method is called, the bean factory reads al the available configurations (e.g. XML files, Groovy scripts, `@Configuration` classes, other) and registers all the encountered bean definitions.

`getBeansWithAnnotation()` should find a `Foo` bean, if it wasn't created from it's bean definition before it will be created when you request it in `@PostConstrust`. You can try to force this scenario with [`@DependsOn`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html) however it may lead to circular dependency problem:

```
@Component
@DependsOn("testBean")
@CustomAnnotation
public class Foo {
}

@Service("testBean")
public class TestBean {

   @Autoware
   private Application context;

   @PostContruct
   public void init() {
      context.getBeansWithAnnotation(CustomAnnotation.class);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, Is that means the Foo bean will be initialized in init()?

Comment: Potentially, if it wasn't initialized before. However you also may get a proxy object if `Foo` is `@Lazy` or annotated with something like `@Transactional`.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot, you let me know more about the life cycle of bean in Spring.

Comment: I googled autowared but could not find any resource. @Karol Dowbecki